# Resizing tensorflow images with unknown size

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a tensorflow UNet-style network.  Currently I specify the input and target images as follows:

```
self.inputTensors = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, opt.inputHeight, opt.inputWidth, opt.inputChannels], name='inputTensors')
self.targetColors = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, opt.inputHeight, opt.inputWidth, opt.outputChannels], name='targetColors')
```

But I would like it to be able to operate on variable width and height images as well, i.e.

```
self.inputTensors = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, opt.inputChannels], name='inputTensors')
self.targetColors = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, opt.outputChannels], name='targetColors')
```

And infer the width and height of the intermediate layers.  This works fine for my pooling layers or strided convolution layers, but for the upsampling layers I am using tf.image.resize_bilinear (although the question is valid for any of tf.image.resize_images.)  Currently my resize bilinear code looks like:

```
def unpool2xBilinear(inputs, name = 'unpool2xBilinear'):
    sh = inputs.get_shape().as_list()
    newShape = (sh[1] * 2, sh[2] * 2)
    return tf.image.resize_bilinear(inputs, newShape)
```

However, this cannot handle unknown input shapes, giving

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Is there a way to allow resize images to accept input-dependent sizes? Or do I have to build an entirely new graph for each different input image size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tf.shape` instead:

```
def unpool2xBilinear(inputs, name = 'unpool2xBilinear'):
    sh = tf.shape(inputs)
    newShape = 2 * sh[1:3]
    return tf.image.resize_bilinear(inputs, newShape)
```