# How do I resize image with unknown size in Tensorflow(tf.shape(input) method doesn't work)

Tags: python, tensorflow

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410154/resizing-tensorflow-images-with-unknown-size), one can use tf.shape() to resize image with unknown size like placeholder. But the method doesn't seem to work for me. I have some simple code that looks like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def speed_tune(x, lower_bound=0.8, upper_bound=2.0):
    speed_rate = np.random.uniform(lower_bound, upper_bound)
    newshape = tf.shape(x)[1:] # get the tensor shape except for rank 0(None)
    newshape *= speed_rate # randomly stretch or compress the signal 
    return tf.resize(x, newshape)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int16, (None, 1000)) # x is a 1D audio signal
y = speed_tune(x)
data = np.random.randint(10, size=1000)
output = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x:data})
```

Basically, my code does the following: Given an input 1D data x, the program tries to stretch or compress the sequence by some random factor and return the tuned sequence. Since I didn't find any Tensorflow function that directly performs this operation, I use tf.resize by treating the data as 1xD image where D is the length of the signal. But I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\SVNRepo\Python_codes\scratch.py", line 33, in <module>
    y = speed_tune(x)
  File "d:\SVNRepo\Python_codes\scratch.py", line 28, in speed_tune
    newshape *= speed_rate # randomly stretch or compress the signal 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'Tensor' and 'float'
```

So it seems like `tf.shape(x)` returns a Tensor rather than integer values that specify the shape of the tensor(verified by [Tensorflow document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape)). How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly are you looking for, but maybe this will help
Used `tf.random.uniform` to avoid tensor/float operation

```
def speed_tune(x, lower_bound=1, upper_bound=2):
    speed_rate = tf.random.uniform([1,], lower_bound, upper_bound, dtype=tf.int32)
    newshape = tf.shape(x)[1:] # get the tensor shape except for rank 0(None)
    newshape = newshape * speed_rate # randomly stretch or compress the signal
    return tf.reshape(x, newshape)
```

Used `tf.reshape`, not sure what you meant by `tf.resize`

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None, 1000)) # x is a 1D audio signal
y = speed_tune(x)
data = np.random.rand(1, 1000)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(y, feed_dict={x:data})
```

Another way is to use `tf.pad`:
For example:

```
n = 10
tensor = tf.constant(np.random.rand(1, 10))
paddings = tf.constant([[0,1], [0,0]])
```

this exact pad setup means that you add n zeros in the end of tensor. In order to get initial dimension you reshape it

```
padded = tf.pad(tensor, paddings)
output  = tf.reshape(padded, [1,n*2])
```

Comment: From my understanding, tf.reshape() requires the product of input ranks equal to that of the new shape. However, what I am looking for is to randomly change the length of a 1D array. For example if the input tensor is 1x1000 and the speed_rate is 1.2, the expected output should be 1x1200. New elements can be generated using some signal processing techniques such as linear interpolation.

Comment: Try `tf.pad`, I added it to answer. You can set any shape you want, or even substitute zeros for something else